# Weird behavior of Cypress spy() function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, cypress

I have a weird problem in Cypress test wen spying on vue component methods. I’ve set a minimal example component for demonstration.

```
<template>
  <button @click="testMethod()”>Button</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ExampleComponent",
  methods: {
    testMethod () {
      console.log(this.testMethod) // for debugging purposes
      console.log("Button clicked")
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And this is the test:

```
import { mount } from "@cypress/vue"
import exampleComponent from "../example"

it("should spy on testMethod", () => {
  mount(exampleComponent).then(() => {
    cy.spy(Cypress.vueWrapper.vm, "testMethod").as("testMethodSpy")
    cy.get("button").click()
    cy.get("@testMethodSpy").should("be.calledOnce")
  })
})
```

When I run this test, it passes ok. In console I get:

```
ƒ testMethod
Button clicked
```

But if I pass the ‘testMethod’ pointer to the @click directive, like this:

```
<template>
  <button @click="testMethod”>Button</button>
</template>
```

then the test fails. It complains about the method never being called even if in console I get.

```
ƒ testMethodSpy
Button clicked
```

I cannot understand why cypress cannot register the call when the method is passed to an event directive, even if it is called.
Also, why the method name change to `testMethodSpy` (the alias that I've set in test) when it fails.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I found that Cypress spy() is wrapping the method along with its context. Passing the method to another component, will change its context, so it will not be counted as a call. To be able to record its calls in the current component, I had to pass the current context also.

```
<child-component :propMethod="parentMethod.apply(this)">
```

Comment: This is totally correct. Good job. A good example of the old classic context "this" in JS.